# Need a CDN with SSL

Tags: https, cdn

We currently use Edgecast through Speedyrails. Back when I did my research they were both fast and very cost-effective.

I haven't looked in a while, but now we need SSL on our assets as well.

I reached out to our current provider and they want a setup fee and something like 260 USD **per host per month** (we use multiple hosts currently).

I looked at [AWS Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) and it seems the most cost affective way to get SSL, but it's not a custom domain then (e.g. cdn.example.org), which I could live with.

Has any else researched this lately and has any providers to get in touch with - can be resellers or direct buys. I'm not looking for a bargain, I just want to get an idea what these things cost.

**Edit, 2012-08-23**: Must have is custom origin. E.g. I don't want to manually upload files somewhere else. Edgecast and Cloudfront both support this.

Comment: So we went with Cloudfront for the time being. It was simple to setup and it works. The URLs are neither branded nor exactly pretty, but that's not a problem for us right now.

Answer (score 3):

Rackspace Cloud Files provides Akamai's SSL enabled CDN. You can configure your CDN with pretty names too. You can ask Rackspace directly, being their managed customer, they will do the all things. But the cost is prohibitive.

Otherwise you can ask on this non commercial website named [thecustomizewindows](http://thecustomizewindows.com/). I found it from Google after searching with another issue for my Rackspace unmanaged to fix an issue of unmanaged Rackspace server and reached there. I do not have any idea whether they are reseller or not because I had my own unmanaged, it was a question about API integration. But I think from 2 email exchanges, the writer can suggest you anything through comments. In my opinion its better to ask him as you might end up with mixed content error with SSL after paying money.

Comment: Can you use their offering with a custom origin? I should have added this to my question, but custom origin (sometimes also called "transparent proxy") is one of the great features of Edgecast or Cloudfront as well. The CDN pulls files directly from my server, which means less management-overhead. Couldn't figure out if Rackspace allowed that as well.

Answer (score 2):

[MaxCDN](http://www.maxcdn.com/pricing) charges $39/month per SSL hostname and if you have a few of them or prepay for a period you can probably negotiate a better price.

Answer (score 0):

[CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans) has an ssl product for $20 a month and $5 extra for each domain. But sound like you are more will be more interested in their business plan which is $200 per domain a month.

Comment: I wouldn't call Cloudflare a CDN since it's basically a proxy which sits in front of your web application and caches everything aggressively. Cloudflare works nicely (I use it for my personal blog), but there are a few ins and outs as far as HTTP is concerned. I'd rather use something like Fastly then.